# jquery effects after load

Tags: jquery

My slideDown effects didn't showup after invoking load method , my code is :

```
$("#outerDiv").load("vacation.do #innerDiv",{},function () {$("#outerDiv").slideDown("slow");});
```

What's the problem ?

Comment: I can't find any syntax error... please try firebug to see if there is another error we are not aware of based on your codes...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The #outerDiv does not exist when Your code is being run.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
     //put Your code here so that it runs when all the HTML content
     // is already parsed by the browser
    });
```

this is a more understandable version of the `$(function(){ /* your code */ });` mentioned before.